# How to drive a motor by Python

Tags: motor, python

I need to drive any small motor (with small delay) by Python without low level programming. What hardware and software I need? Does "Robot Mesh Studio" fit for this? I want to make a robotic friend to my dog but don't want him to damage a rospberry pi. I am on my start on robotics science so I didn't try anything.

Comment: Python + raspberry pi gpio / microcontroller + motor driver + motor.. and walla! You are done..

Comment: Just google rhe detail..

Comment: https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* bluesky, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.